# Jersey Obfuscating Collections in JSON Output

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

In my code I can see I am returning a valid Object. This object happens to contain a collection of 'user comments'. This collection is valid and filled with entries right before I return the Response object through JAX-RS. However, when the GET request is completed that collection is mysteriously replaced by a boolean value denoting if the collection is empty or not.

Just to reiterate. Valid, non-empty collection, returned in a GET request as a boolean with field 'empty'

What gives? I know there must be some magic under the hood, but it has been escaping me.

```
@GET
@Path("{issue: \\w+-\\d+}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getIssue(@PathParam("issue") String issue) {
    Issue returnedIssue = null;
    try {
        returnedIssue = jiraService.getIssue(issue);
    }
    catch (RestClientException ex) {
        log.error("ERROR: Could not find issue " + issue + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        throwErrorResponse(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return getResponse(Response.Status.OK, returnedIssue);
}
```

This is my POJO: http://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/1.0/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/domain/Issue.html

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Add the `getResponse` method to your question as well.